# Wpf Treeview bind base on Project Folder Structure

Tags: wpf, treeview, binding, treeviewitem

I currently have a catalog of files I want to read into my program in my Project.
Structure.

```
Project
   - Properties
   - References
   - Manufacturers (want to project this as treeview)
      - Honda
         - file1
         - file2
      - Toyota
         - file1
         - file2
```

In my program each file above is represented by its own business object.
I want to be able to in my program have this in my treeview.

```
- Honda
     - file1
     - file2
- Toyota
     - file1
     - file2
```

I only load these file once so I want to just read these file once and bind them to the tree view. Is there an elegant way to do this???

Thanks,
Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28VS.95%29.aspx)

```
<toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" >
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
</toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ManufacturerTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<toolkit:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ManufacturerTemplate}"/>
```

Your business objects could look something like this...

```
class Manufacturer
{
     String Name {get; set;}
     ObservableCollection<File> Files {get; set;}

}

class File
{
     String FileName {get; set;}
}
```

You would then set the `DataContext` of the `TreeView` to `ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>`

Comment: thanks, i just have a question though, where is FileTemplate being used, secondly, does this mean i have to store the folder name "Manufacturer" in my business object?

Comment: @Kev84 Typo with regard to FileTemplate, corrected that...added sample business objects

Comment: is there a way I can do this without adding a manufacturer business object, and just use File and its PathName??

Comment: @Kev84 You would lose the hierarchical aspect then...it would become flat since your file would be at the same tier as your manufacturer. A parent -> child relationship exists; no way around that with the current requirements. You could manually build out the tree but using the HierarchicalDataTemplate and putting a wrapper object in place would be a much more robust and elegant approach.